# Error when deploying an angular 2 application on bluemix using angular-cli

Tags: angular, ibm-cloud, devops, angular-cli, broccolijs

We are trying to deploy an angular 2 application on bluemix. We have defined a pipeline that builds and deploys the project, but we are stuck in the build fase. The build process is using angular-cli to prepare a folder for deploy (ng build --prod) but it fails on:

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliMergeTrees] failed with:
Error: Merge error: file index.html exists in /home/pipeline/7c14494a-d2b2-417f-be02-1007a2c8cfe7/tmp/broccoli_merge_trees-input_base_path-2MsSutn8.tmp/0 and /home/pipeline/7c14494a-d2b2-417f-be02-1007a2c8cfe7/tmp/broccoli_merge_trees-input_base_path-2MsSutn8.tmp/1
```

This should work with the latest version of node, but no node version above 4.2.2. seems to be available during the build process.
Any Ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We faced this too for one demo that required Node 4.4. Here is how we have setup our build pipeline. We get *nvm* during the build and then install any version of Node:

```
#!/bin/bash
# nvm is not compatible with this option
npm config delete prefix
# get nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.2/install.sh | bash
# load nvm    
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
# install Node 4.4
nvm install 4.4

# proceed with our specific code...
npm install
```